# Installing Jekyll with gem

Tags: ruby, gem

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

I am trying to install Jekyll through gem with

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

but I get this error at some point of the installation:

```
ERROR:  While generating documentation for jekyll-0.12.1
... MESSAGE:   Unhandled special: Special: type=17, text="<!-- more -->"
... RDOC args: --ri --op /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/jekyll-0.12.1/ri --charset=UTF-8 lib README.textile LICENSE --title jekyll-0.12.1 Documentation --quiet
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948913/error-while-executing-gem-with-local-gem/14949087#14949087

Comment: But why install doesnt work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo gem install rdoc
```

Then

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

you can see the answer at https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/762

Comment: "sudo" should be used with/for non-privileged users only .

Answer (score 1):

I'll brave enough to post another answer.
I've just installed Jekyll on Ubuntu 12.04, so I hope that this piece of text will save somebody's time.

Firstly, you'll have problems with `ruby-1.8`.

You should install `ruby-1.9` as described [here](https://leonard.io/blog/2012/05/installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pengolin/):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev rubygems1.9.1 irb1.9.1 ri1.9.1 rdoc1.9.1 build-essential libopenssl-ruby1.9.1 libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 400 \
        --slave   /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz ruby.1.gz \
                        /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.9.1.1.gz \
        --slave   /usr/bin/ri ri /usr/bin/ri1.9.1 \
        --slave   /usr/bin/irb irb /usr/bin/irb1.9.1 \
        --slave   /usr/bin/rdoc rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc1.9.1
```

choose your interpreter
changes symlinks for `/usr/bin/ruby`, `/usr/bin/gem`,
`/usr/bin/irb`, `/usr/bin/ri` and `man (1) ruby`

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
sudo update-alternatives --config gem
```

now try

```
ruby --version
```

Unfortunately, this is not enough.
May be some commands here are odd and you can install `jekyll` without them...
But let them be. Maybe somebody will improve  my answer.

As of 2016-11-26, `jekyll` and `rdoc` required `ruby-2.2`.
Install it [as described](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2015/01/05/ruby-2-2-0-packages-for-ubuntu/):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2 ruby2.2-dev
ruby2.2 -v
```

Then install `rdoc` and `jekyll`:

```
sudo gem install rdoc jekyll
```

Update alternatives again:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
sudo update-alternatives --config gem
```

Of course, you should choose `*2.2`

Finally, now you can install `jekyll`:

```
sudo gem install rdoc jekyll
```