# How to install jekyll?

Tags: software-installation, ruby, jekyll

According to the [jekyll site](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/), this is how you make a new website with jekyll:

```
~ $ gem install jekyll
~ $ jekyll new myblog
~ $ cd myblog
~/myblog $ jekyll serve
```

`gem install jekyll` didn't work, nor did `sudo gem install jekyll`:

```
└─>gem install jekyll
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/LICENSE
┌─[Sat Jun 08][jon@jon-MacMini:~/Web]
└─>sudo !!
sudo gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

I also tried following [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259823/installing-jekyll-with-gem), but that doesn't help. `sudo apt-get install jekyll` works. Even then, though, running `jekyll new myblog` returns this error:

```
└─>jekyll new myblog
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
WARNING: Could not read configuration. Using defaults (and options).
    No such file or directory - new/_config.yml
Building site: new -> myblog
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:126:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /home/jon/Web/new/ (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:126:in `read_directories'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:98:in `read'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:38:in `process'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:250:in `<main>'
```

Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04. I installed ruby the usual way: `sudo apt-get install ruby`.

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/853809/493548).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

On my 13.04 and 14.04 systems, things worked for me after installing the ruby-dev package, then running the gem install:

- `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev` (or try: `ruby-dev` instead)
- `gem install jekyll` # if this fails then `sudo gem install jekyll`

After that, jekyll was installed correctly.

Note that for the `gem install` instruction, it is better not to use sudo.*****

It's better to use something like RVM, so that `sudo` isn't required. On some systems  it may be necessary to use `sudo`, if for instance permissions were set by previous sudo commands or root-level configuration.

See this [stackoverflow question -- how to install gems without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643629/how-to-install-gems-without-sudo) for more information and for help on getting permissions set to user instead of root.

***** Credit to @iguarav for this best practices advice as well as the link to [rvm.io](https://rvm.io).

Comment: That worked. I also had to add the gem directory to my PATH, though, in order to be able to run `jekyll` from the command-line. I also had to uninstall the ubuntu package version, which doesn't have the `new` subcommand.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, I first tried installing and using ruby2.0-dev but without luck.

Comment: confirmed to work at ubuntu 14.04

Comment: you should not use sudo with gem install since these are just reusable libraries

Comment: @belacqua best practices recommend usage of RVM https://rvm.io/ . if you use sudo excessively , you soon will be facing dependency problems .

Comment: @Jon Where did you find the jekyll gem directory? i can not find it under  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems

Comment: @javadba  If you are using these instructions, look under /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 instead.   Do you have a `/var/lib/gems` at all?

Answer (score 3):

**Guide for 14.04 LTS without RVM**

Jekyll 3 needs ruby 2.0 or higher, so we first install ruby 2.0, it's development headers and nodejs:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ruby2.0 ruby2.0-dev nodejs
```

Then we point the commands included in the ruby package to the new version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.0 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gem gem /usr/bin/gem2.0 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/irb irb /usr/bin/irb2.0 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/rdoc rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc2.0 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/testrb testrb /usr/bin/testrb2.0 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/rake rake /usr/bin/rake2.0 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/erb erb /usr/bin/erb2.0 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ri ri /usr/bin/ri2.0 10
```

And finally we use `gem` to install the jekyll gem.

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you don't want to depend on `sudo` for executing `gems`, so I recommend to add your user to the root's group and:

```
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/lib/gems
sudo chmod -R 770 /usr/local/bin
```

Just doing a few updates on this thread. According the [jekyll's installation docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/) the version needed is version 2. After fixing the permissions issue, I ran into that expected error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
jekyll requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

Installing with RVM:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys \  409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby             
/bin/bash --login
rvm install 2.3.0
rvm use 2.3.0
rvm rubygems latest
ruby --version
rvm install ruby-dev
```

> For other issues with the Ruby installation, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222738/how-do-i-install-ruby-2-0-0-correctly-on-ubuntu-12-04).

After that, it worked for me.