# Can install Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 with Ruby 2.1.3

Tags: 14.04, ruby, rails

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I wanted to use the latest ruby (version 2.1.3), so I installed it with RVM.

```
rvm install ruby --latest
rvm use ruby --latest --default
```

But when I try to install Rails, i get the following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install jekyll?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/305884/how-to-install-jekyll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, `mkmf` is in the `ruby-dev` package:

```
rvm install 1.9.1-dev
```

Install manually with `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev` (depending on your version).

Comment: will it work, even if im using ruby 2.1.3?

Comment: Wow, that did work. It doesnt make any sense to me, but thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I followed the steps no this blog. It was helpful. 
http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you/

Lastly, you'll want to free up space by telling Rubygems not to install the documentation for each package locally, run:
echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. While it is always good to cite one's sources at least the important parts to answer a question should be posted here. There is no guarantee that the linked website will remain as it is and thus be useful in the future.