# How to install Rails?

Tags: command-line, apt, ruby

I can't find this specific error in the web but when typing `sudo gem install rails -v 5.2.2` I get the following error:

```
    nysa@nysa-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo gem install rails -v 5.2.2
Fetching activesupport-5.2.2.gem
Fetching actionview-5.2.2.gem
Fetching actionpack-5.2.2.gem
Fetching railties-5.2.2.gem
Fetching activerecord-5.2.2.gem
Fetching activemodel-5.2.2.gem
Fetching activestorage-5.2.2.gem
Fetching actioncable-5.2.2.gem
Fetching activejob-5.2.2.gem
Fetching actionmailer-5.2.2.gem
Fetching rails-5.2.2.gem
Successfully installed activesupport-5.2.2
Successfully installed actionview-5.2.2
Successfully installed actionpack-5.2.2
Successfully installed railties-5.2.2
Successfully installed activemodel-5.2.2
Successfully installed activerecord-5.2.2
Successfully installed activestorage-5.2.2
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -I /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20190626-19849-1302wcu.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/websocket-driver-0.7.1/gem_make.out
```

Looks like I have already a rails version installed but when typing `rails -v` I get a message that 'rails' doesn't exist.
How can I make install the latest version of Rails and make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Installing rails involves compiling some C source code, which requires the [header files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive#C/C++) of whatever libraries the C code happens to use. At minimum, the `ruby-dev` package must be installed, as that provides the header files for Ruby itself. The specific error you've seen appears to be due to its absence, since `/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h` is absence.

[Installing `ruby-dev` is often sufficient to solve this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26161563/1038860) However, I've found that, on recent Ubuntu systems that don't have `zlib1g-dev` installed, I need that too. My guess is that people often have it installed already and that this is why it is less often necessary to install.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev
```

After you install those packages, you can simply run your `gem install` command again. If there are more errors that talk about not being able to find header files, you can install the appropriate `-dev` packages, but I don't expect there to be anything else you need to install.

Installing `ruby-dev` also [sometimes fixes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305884/how-to-install-jekyll) `gem install` problems whose error mentions don't name a missing header file.

---

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might also consider the alternatives of:

- installing Rails via the `rails` package (`sudo apt install rails`), though that may not give you the version you want if you need a specific version, *or*
- installing Rails with `gem install` *without* `sudo`, so that it is installed in your home directory (which [you should be able to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643629/how-to-install-gems-without-sudo)), *or*
- [other methods that let you a specifically desired version of Ruby as well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails).