# How to install rubygems in Ubuntu 12.04 with Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

So I used these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby 1.9.3
cd /etc/alternatives
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3 ruby
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078166/how-do-i-install-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-without-rvm in order to get ruby 1.9.3 and make it the default. That appears to have worked fine.

Now when I attempt to use gem install it tells me the gems are already the latest. However, when I attempt to run a script it tells me it can't find the gem I require on the first line. Long story short, this script didn't work in ruby 1.8.7 due to an error farther down in the code but did get past the require lines without issue.

So I expected to and assume I need to reinstall all my 1.8.7 gems for 1.9.3 or at least figure out how to point 1.9.3 at the gems I've installed.

How do I do get usable gems for 1.9.3?

Comment: You can use first part of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259823/installing-jekyll-with-gem/853809#853809).

Answer (score 4):

Do you also have ruby1.8 and rubygems installed?  Uninstall them, or at least rubygems ("sudo apt-get remove rubygems").  Ubuntu 12.04's ruby1.9.3 package includes a version of rubygems, no additional package needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. At this point I've gone to RVM though and everything seems to work well enough using it. If someone tests this and says it works, I'll mark it as the answer. I just don't have the time to mess with it and risk it breaking things that are working. Thanks again.